# Evaluate $\int^1_0 (9x^9-x^{90}+9x^{99}-x^{900}+9x^{909}-x^{990}+9x^{999}-x^{9000}+\cdots){\rm d}x$ (From MIT integration Bee Semi-final 2023)

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I am trying to evaluate a question from MIT Integration Bee Semi-final 2023 (candidates had to solve it within 3 minutes!):$$\int^1_0 (9x^9-x^{90}+9x^{99}-x^{900}+9x^{909}-x^{990}+9x^{999}-x^{9000}+\cdots){\rm d}x$$ The pattern of the index is $9$*$(1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, \cdots)$, just like the binary sequence. However, I have no idea how to apply the sum of infinite series in this case. The answer for this integral is simply $1$.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You know that $\int_0^1 x^n = 1/(n+1)$, so try to apply that to every term and turn it to a sum. Hopefully that sum will be familiar to you.

Comment: There is something to notice about the powers....If you could use a substitution such as $x=ln(t)$, you could obtain a series such as: https://oeis.org/A097256

Comment: For additional context, please mention the source. Edit your question. In fact I found a source, which is [this one](https://math.mit.edu/~yyao1/pdf/2023_semifinal.pdf). For example, useful context is that the "winner" of the Integration Bee should be doing this in about 3 minutes, this was a "semifinal" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternate solution that utilises an infinite product and parity. First, we can construct the function $f(x) = (1+x^9)(1+x^{90})(1+x^{900})(1+x^{9000})\cdots = 1 + x^9 + x^{99} + x^{900} + x^{909}+\cdots$ that generates all the required powers for our integrand. With some manipulation, we can determine that $$f(-x) = (1-x^9)(1+x^{90})(1+x^{900})(1+x^{9000})\cdots,$$ and so
\begin{align*} f_{odd}(x) &= \frac{1}{2}(f(x)-f(-x)),\\
&= x^9(1+x^{90})(1+x^{900})(1+x^{9000})\cdots,\\
&= x^9f(x^{10}). \end{align*}
Thus, the original integral is \begin{align*} I &= \int_{0}^{1} (9x^{9}-x^{90}+9x^{909} -x^{990} +9x^{999} -\cdots)\ dx,\\
&= \int_{0}^{1} [9f_{odd}(x)-f_{even}(x) + 1]\ dx,\\
&= 1+ \int_{0}^{1} [10f_{odd}(x)-(f_{even}(x)+f_{odd}(x))]\ dx,\\
&= 1+\int_{0}^{1} [10x^9f(x^{10})-f(x)]\ dx,\\
&= 1+\int_{0}^{1} f(t) dt - \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\ dx,\\
&= 1, \end{align*}
where we have used the substitution $t=x^{10}$.

Answer (score 8):

The key idea in this question is that one should know how to break the integral into appropriate parts so that it's clear what is going on.

Indeed, the identification of indices is correct. However, the signs haven't been specified yet. To make things precise, I'll start over again.

---

The set of "exponents" $S$ is clearly equal to all positive integers whose decimal representation consists only of $0$ and $9$, such as $990, 9099$ etc.

Now, if the last digit of $S$ is a $9$ then the sign is positive (and the resulting monomial is multiplied by $9$) , otherwise the sign is negative.

---

One is tempted to take the positive and negative parts aside : if one does this, though, then you truly lose sight of what is the key step here.

The key step here is the recognition that $$
\frac{1}{9} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^i}
$$
and therefore, $$
1 =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{10^i} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 9x^{10^i-1}dx
$$

This shows you how combining some of the powers in the sum above might result in the number $1$. However, we can easily combine this to "cover" other powers as well. Indeed, for any positive integer $s$, \begin{equation}
\int_0^1 x^{s}dx = \frac{1}{s+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{(s+1)10^i} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 9x^{(s+1)10^i-1}dx \tag{1} \label{1}
\end{equation}
Let's see how this looks on paper. Take $s = 90$. Then, this looks like $$
\int_{0}^1 x^{90}dx = \int_0^1 (9x^{909} +9x^{9099}+9x^{90999}+\ldots)
$$
Then let's look at $s = 990$. This looks like $$
\int_0^1 x^{990}dx = \int_0^1 (9x^{9909}+9x^{99099}+9x^{990999} + \ldots)
$$

and you can see where this is going! If you make this observation within two minutes of the clock elapsing on this problem, you should be done before the buzzer, provided you can formalize things.

---

Naturally, the formalization is quite easy now. Let $S' \subset S$ be all those exponents ending in a $0$.

Then, summing $\eqref{1}$ over $s\in S'$, we have \begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \sum_{s \in S'} x^{s}dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{s\in S'} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 9x^{(s+1)10^i-1}dx \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}

However, observe that every number of the form $(s+1)10^i-1, s \in S', i \geq 1$ is in one-to-one correspondence with an exponent in $S\setminus S'$, that does NOT have all its digits as $9$. For example

- If you take $90909$ then this equals $90910-1 = (9090+1)10-1$ which corresponds to $s = 9090,i=1$.
- If you take $90099999$ then this equals $90100000-1 = (900+1)10^5 - 1$ which corresponds to $s = 900, i=5$.

A visual way of describing this bijection is that you take the number in question, find the number of nines it ends with (which equals $i$), remove all those to get the number $s$). For example, $90099999$ ends with $i=5$ nines and removing them gives $s=900$.

This way, \eqref{2} rearranges itself to \begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{s \in S'} x^{s}dx - \sum_{s\in S'} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 9x^{(s+1)10^i-1}\right)dx =0\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}

By the previous observations and $\eqref{3}$, all those exponents $S$ in the integral to be computed cancel out, except those that *only contain $9$ as a digit*. Consequently,
$$
I= \int_0^1 \left(9x^9 - x^{90}+9x^{99} - x^{900} +9x^{909} - x^{990} + 9x^{999} - x^{9000} + \ldots\right) dx \\
= \int_0^1 9x^9+9x^{99}+9x^{999} + \ldots dx \\
= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{10^i} = 1
$$
by the geometric series , concluding the proof.

---

I think it's important to notice *how* the integral was broken up. Simply combining the positive signs blindly, or combining all monomials with exponents having the same number of digits etc., these are all blind alleys to some extent. Therefore, having the right approach, and having it in *three minutes* at that, it's quite incredible (read the comment below the question).

Also note that I have freely exchanged integral and sum everywhere, and I'm not going to justify Fubini's theorem being used here, it probably can be used quite liberally without proof in competitions.

Comment: It is a really nice solution that integrating each negative x term can eliminate the other positive $9x^n$ terms.

Comment: @HeyFan I agree as well! I have just a small request to you, if you don't mind : in the comments below your question, I have left a link to the actual question, and the "extra comments", such as it being a semifinal question and having to be solved in under 3 minutes. I think adding this makes your question really interesting, and someone else might be able to get a great answer (and I think it will get more votes as well), so I suggest you edit your post by adding that comment. Otherwise, great question, thanks a lot for asking it.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my post and welcome to all "nice" solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I hope you ask more good questions like this in the future @HeyFan because we need them!

Comment: Another great answer from your end. +1 Still find it hard to believe that a winner could do this in 3 minutes.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I did it in about $4$ minutes, honestly. It took me very little time to write down, before I modified and labelled it carefully. My other answer yesterday took $100$ minutes, which shows that time spent is not proportional to votes, not even close!